# How js can parse this 'clustering, metric 1,' as a date?

Tags: javascript, date

Title,

```
> new Date('clustering, metric 1,')
> Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

So `Date.parse('clustering, metric 1,')` return true, it's an issue for my type detection, how can this be parsed as a date, it's not even close.

**edit:**
@evolutionxbox that's probably the reason, it's very naive. I guess the solution is to make a regex for every date format. If someone got references about date detection he's welcome.

Comment: Your type detection consists of trying to parse random values as dates…? I'd say the problem is *there*.

Comment: The same way:

`> new Date('ffffff, ffff, 1');
< Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`
followed by
`> new Date('1');
< Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

Comment: It's reading everything before the `1` as the month.

Comment: use this instead? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/x32xj5de/

Comment: You can only reliably parse a string to a Date if you know the format and provide that format to the parser. Anything else is leaving it to chance. The built-in parser doesn't accept a parse format, so it is extremely unreliable (as you've discovered). :-( BTW, in Safari `new Date('clustering, metric 1,')` returns an invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) to parse dates. You can check if a date is valid this way:

```
moment("clustering, metric 1,", ["MM-DD-YYYY", "YYYY-MM-DD"], true).isValid(); // false
```

The 3rd parameter instructs moment to use strict parsing (available in version 2.3.0 and above).

Comment: While suggesting to use something other than the built-in parser is a good idea, this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: That's true it doesn't answer the question. However, it helps to solve the problem, I hope.